# Supported video formats for Youtube

Tags: video, upload, youtube

Which are the video formats that Youtube supports? (like avi, ...)

Comment: [I'm out of close votes but] it sounds like this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I would've thought the best chance of being on topic would be over at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ (if it hasn't already been answered there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a and some below here are containers of formats, and itself can support formats:

- Windows Media Video (.WMV)
- 3GP (Cell Phones)
- AVI (Windows)
- MOV (Mac)
- MP4 (iPod/PSP)
- MPEG / MPEGPS
- FLV (Flash)
- SWF (Flash)
- MKV (h.264)
- WebM

Even if it is not on the list, automatically YouTube attempts to recognize it. So for example if you have a container like Ogg or Ogv, then thy would most likely work. But if you have 'custom' data with a non-open standard like Microsoft Expression Encoder file, then YouTube can not parse that.

For more information about what format to use check out:

- http://www.ifunia.com/youtube-column/best-youtube-video-format.html
- http://www.youtube.com/handbook_popup_produce_upload?pcont=bestformats

Answer (score 0):

Here's what [the documentation](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55744) says:

- WebM files - Vp8 video codec and Vorbis Audio codecs
- .MPEG4, 3GPP and MOV files - Typically supporting h264, mpeg4 video codecs, and AAC audio codec
- .AVI - Many cameras output this format - typically the video codec is MJPEG and audio is PCM
- .MPEGPS - Typically supporting MPEG2 video codec and MP2 audio
- .WMV
- .FLV - Adobe-FLV1 video codec, MP3 audio

Answer (score 0):

For uploading videos: http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55744

When watching a video, default is through H264 enclosed in an FLV. You can switch that to pure H264 if you're using Chrome browser and you select to participate in the HTML5 beta.